# is the following code vulnerable to dom-based xss?

Tags: javascript, security, dom, xss

A security auditor reported me that the following snippet of html/js is vulnerable to XSS.

In short this is it:

```js
if (window.location.hash) {
        var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
        var elem = $('#reports_nav_links .' + hash);
        var path = elem.data('path');
```

the security auditor didn't provide any detail on how this can be leveraged to get an alert box showing.

The url generated by default is:

/report#q1

If it's vulnerable, could you also please provide me an example of payload that will show an alert box with this code?

Thanks,
Dan.

Comment: Can't see it. jQuery only evaluates the selector as string and throws exception if it can't parse it properly as valid selector and it only uses string methods for that parsing

Comment: I'm guessing they have a policy that since `$()` can also accept html that can then be injected in dom that any unsanitized variables that are assigned from external sources used inside `$()` are a security issue

Comment: @charlietfl You are right, so you are saying that the issue is valid?
What payload could be used to trigger an alert box for example?

Comment: I don't see it being possible to execute anything in this use case since that leading `#` indicates it is being used as a selector. The case where it is more problematic is `hash = "<script>....</script>"; $(hash).appendTo('body')`

Comment: Even then jQuery doesn't like script tags either